# check multiple condition ngIf

Tags: html, angular

I have written a toggle function that changes the text of link . but i need to check for multiple condition . ie , *ngIf="condition1 or conditiong2" .

Here's a cut from my code :

```
<a routerLink="/ads" class="tip" (click)="toggle(value._id)"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i>
<span *ngIf="showActivate[value._id]||value.status='active'">De activate</span>
<span *ngIf="!showActivate[value._id]||value.status='inactive'">Activate</span>
</a>
```

this doesn't work. Please tell me how to properly check for both the condition. all related questions in here didn't help , hence posting this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can u pls post code of `showActivate` and `toggle` functions ?

Comment: I think showActivate is a function, to invoke that function update your code to showActivate(value._id) instead of showActivate[value._id]. New Condition can be showActivate(value._id) || value.status==='active'

Comment: You have written `value.status = ` instead of `value.status === `.

Comment: Yea, It worked :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need `===` when you are comparing a string not `=` which is an assignment

```
<span *ngIf="showActivate[value._id]||value.status==='active'">De activate</span>
<span *ngIf="!showActivate[value._id]||value.status==='inactive'">Activate</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also move these multiple condition to a method in your component.

```
showActivate(value:any): boolean {
 if(value.status === 'active') {
    return true;
 } else {
     return false;
}
```

**Html**

```
<span *ngIf="showActivate()">De activate</span>
```